# Images and text go into the header when I scroll

Tags: android

Every time I scroll down the screen, the images and text keep going into the header and interfering with the header, can anyone tell where I went wrong in the xml file? I'm pretty sure it's a small thing but I can't seem to see it. Thank you

[image: screenshot]

```
 <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="ie.example.artur.projectrepeat.ScrollActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Potatoe"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_weight="0.95"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@mipmap/potatoe"
            android:layout_weight="0.61"
            android:contentDescription="potatoe1" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Tomatoe"
            android:id="@+id/textView7" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@mipmap/tomatoe"
            android:layout_weight="0.44" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Carrots"
            android:id="@+id/textView8" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/carrot"
            android:layout_weight="0.61" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Onions"
            android:id="@+id/textView9" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@mipmap/potatoe"
            android:layout_weight="0.36" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Apples"
            android:id="@+id/textView10" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/apples"
            android:layout_weight="0.30" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Oranges"
            android:id="@+id/textView11" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/oranges" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Strawberries"
            android:id="@+id/textView12" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/strawberry" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Bananas"
            android:id="@+id/textView13" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/bananas" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Lettuce"
            android:id="@+id/textView14" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/letucce" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Pears"
            android:id="@+id/textView15" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/pears" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with the problem?

Comment: I added the link to the image now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with this XML. It's on the main layout.

- Your toolbar must be the last element in the XML
- or you have to use `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_below`
- or you have to use `LinearLayout` and `orientation="vertical"`